# Segmentation Fault when attempting to print value in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

The following C code returns a "segmentation fault" error. I do not understand why it does not return the value 20. What is my error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int* n;
    *n = 20;

    printf("%i\n",*n);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: 'n' is an uninitialized pointer value that you're dereferencing in the line '*n = 20'.  If you wish to use a pointer, you need to make sure that you initialize it to point at a valid memory location before you try to dereference it.

Comment: Alternatively to the answers already given, you could just `int n=20` and pass `&n` (the address of n), to whatever functions needs `int*` as parameter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You haven't allocated memory to `n`, so

```
*n = 20;
```

attempts to write unspecified memory.

Try

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
/* use n */
free(n);
```

Answer (score 5):

You haven't allocated space for your `int`, you've only declared a *pointer* to an `int`.

The pointer is uninitialized, and so writing to that unknown space in memory is undefined behavior and causes problems. This typically causes a segfault.

You can allocate a slot for an integer using `malloc`:

```
n = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

And use a corresponding call to `free` to free up the memory later:

```
free(n);
```

But allocating a single slot for an integer is pretty unusual, typically you would allocate the `int` on the stack:

```
int n;
n = 20;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write `20` in garbage value. You must allocate space for it by using one of `*alloc()` functions or creating an int on stack and getting the andress of it(as Richard J. Ross III mentioned on comments).

**dynamic allocation:**

```
int n*; 
n = malloc(sizeof(int));  /* allocate space for an int */
if(n != NULL) {
 /* do something.. */ 
 free(n); /* free 'n' */
} else {
  /*No space available. */
}
```

or on the **stack:**

```
int int_on_stack;
int *n = &int_on_stack;
*n = 20;
printf("%i\n", *n); // 20
```

Comment: Note that `malloc` isn't the only solution. There is `mmap`, `alloca`, and simply creating an int on the stack and getting the address of it.

Comment: Your stack example isn't consistent with "getting the andress of it". What you want is `int onstack; int n = &onstack; *n = 20;  printf("%i\n",*n);` ... Hey, I've edit privileges, so I went ahead and made the change.