# Can't assign values to variable and pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm very new to C, but have no idea why this program breaks. The program compiles and runs if I remove the lines that have to do with `i`, but if I assign `i`, I can no longer assign anything to `*ptr` without the program breaking.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int *ptr;

    i = 2;
    *ptr = 5;
    printf("%d",*ptr);
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278085/segmentation-fault-when-attempting-to-print-value-in-c) nearly _identical_ question was asked just yesterday.

Comment: The problem is that you have created a pointer, but not given it anything to point to.  You can assign it some memory using the new, or  point it at a variable like i.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You leave the pointer with uninitialized value. So when you dereference it (`*ptr`), you access arbitrary place in memory, resulting in a segmentation fault.

Point `ptr` at something by assigning to `ptr` itself (not `*ptr`) an address of a variable (like `&i`) or some freshly allocated memory (like `malloc(sizeof(int))`).

Comment: So why does it work if I simply use 
`int *ptr;`
`*ptr = 5;`?

Comment: It might "work" or it might crash, depending on your platform, compiler, settings... Either way, it's incorrect. C is an unsafe language and it doesn't check for memory errors, they might slip unnoticed into your program and strike when not expected. :)

Comment: Thanks! I've never worked with a manual memory management language before so this is all new to me. Certainly a lot more to think about.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer for C:

```
int main(void) {
    int i;
    int * ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    i = 2;
    *ptr = 5;     
    printfn("%d",*ptr); 
    free(ptr);
}
```

Alternatively you could for the i and *ptr assignment lines use something like:

```
int main(void) {
    int i;
    int * ptr;

    i = 2;
    ptr = &i;     
    printfn("%d",*ptr); // should print 2
}
```

Notice also that the free came out!!!

Answer (score 1):

You declared ptr but didn't make it point to anything. Then you tried to write to what it points to. This is never a good idea. Try making ptr point to i by adding the line

```
ptr = &i;
```

before you try to write to *ptr

Answer (score 0):

Before using a pointer in C, you need either to set the pointer to an existing block of memory, you need to allocate memory for it, like this.

```
int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```