# Why does command line argument declaration cause segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers

I'm seriously confused. Upon read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278085/segmentation-fault-when-attempting-to-print-value-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297576/cant-assign-values-to-variable-and-pointer)

I decided to give it a try so I sat down a wrote the vanilla code that look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

  int *ptr;
  printf("%p\n:",ptr);
  *ptr = 65;
  printf("PTR : \n \t VALUE: %d\n \t ADDRESS: %p\n",*ptr,ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

And It worked.

```
0x7fff50ba0500
:PTR :
     VALUE: 65
     ADDRESS: 0x7fff50ba0500
```

Now, I have couple (3 to be precise) of question.

**QUESTION 1:**

I know that `int *ptr` is not initialised in the above step. And one of the ways to do it is using.

```
 int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
 *ptr = 65

   or 
 int b = 65;
 int *ptr;
 ptr = &b; // or simply int *ptr = &b;
```

But unlike char pointer it cannot be directly assigned. Example in char pointer world

```
   char *name = "apple";
   or
   char *name;
   name = "viren";
```

Is a valid declaration but the following is not true for other example

```
   int *ptr = 65; // not valid, since ptr should point to address.
```

Any explanation for this why?

**QUESTION 2**

As mention in the other StacK overflow answer

```
*ptr = 65;
```

is bad because ptr must point to a address. In above case it would point to `0x41` address (If by conversion to hex is correct) hence the code will result in `segmentation fault`

Question then why does the above code break and resulted in `Segmentation Fault`.

**QUESTION 3:**
  I have a habit of not writing the command line argument declaration i.e the

i.e

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
```

After I successfully ran the code **without** the command line declaration the first time. (and it resulted in success much to my surprise). I added the command line argument declaration.

But, upon running the same code this time. Resulted in Segmentation Fault.

Question : So why does this difference that the code work without the command line argument but break with command line argument declaration.

Comment: Those questions are completely unrelated. Pick one, or split them into different questions.

Comment: One hint: `int * ptr = y` is the same as `int ptr;` followed by (1) `ptr = y;` or (2) `*ptr = y;`? What's the difference between the two assignments?

Comment: `*ptr = 65` when `ptr` pointer not initialized is an undefined behavior. Best part of your question is an attempt to define undefined, which is completely pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1**:

When you do `char *name = "apple";`, you are specifying that `name` is a character pointer that points to a string literal object "apple". In C, the string literals are stored in a special (read-only) section of the memory. So `name` here points to that section of the memory where the literal "apple" is stored.

However, integer or float literals are usually part of machine instructions and are not stored in memory separately. So your statement `int * p = 65` becomes invalid because the integer literal `65` is not separately stored in memory and hence there is no address that the int pointer can point to.

**Answer 2**:

Your understanding is not quite correct. The statement `*ptr = 65` instructs that the int value of 65 should be stored at the address pointed to by `ptr`. In your case, since you haven't initialized `ptr` with a writable memory, it throws a segmentation fault.

**Answer 3**:

Specifying arguments to the `main` function should not have anything to do with the segmentation fault that you are seeing. The behavior of assigning values to an uninitialized pointer is unpredictable. It may throw segmentation fault or it may not depending on whether the memory location it ends up writing to is writable or not.